# sqoop export hive->oracle error(string/varchar column to clob column)

Tags: hive, sqoop, clob, sqoop2, nclob

```
    [Hive side]
    create table TEST.HIVE_TEST (
    CONTENT string)
    stored as textfile;
    
    [oracle side]
    create table TEST.ORACLE_TEST (
    CONTENT clob);
    
    [sqoop export]
    /usr/bin/sqoop export \
    --connect "connection string"
    --username "ex" password "ex" \
    --table ORACLE_TEST \
    --columns CONTENT \
    --hcatalog-table HIVE_TEST --hcatalog-database TEST \
    --map-column-java CONTENT=String
```

result of mapreduce is successed but when i see the yarn application log
i find
ERROR [main] org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.hcat.SqoopHCatExportHelper : cannot convert hcatalog object of type string to java object type org.apache.sqoop.lib.clobref

and i see null in oracle
what is the solution can anyone help?

sqoop version is Sqoop-1.4.7-cdh6.3.4

i hope anyone knows how to export data from string to clob(oracle) using sqoop

Comment: You can follow this solution. You need to change case or oracle clob column to lowercase and try your sqoop export command https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SQOOP-3254

Comment: when i created table like the DDL in the link you gave me. but when i sqoop export, the error message is like "ORA-00904: "CLOB_COLUMN" invalid identifer

Comment: they used `clob col` name, tiyre using `content`. you need to replace using your colname

Comment: of course, i changed the export command from uppsercase to lowercase but still same error..